# How to retrieve UTF-8 data from SQL database?

Tags: php, sql

After many attempts I couldn't get data from my database in a correct encoding (UTF-8) format.

This is my connection(config.php) file:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "db");
$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
?>
```

My php form for retriving data:

```
<?php 

include('config.php');
$sqlget="SELECT * FROM table";
$sqldata= mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die ('error');
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
echo"<table>";
echo"</table";
?>
```

Comment: If you just did a google query on `php mysqli utf8` you would have wound the answer in the first result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not sending the link identifier
`mysqli_set_charset($dbcon , "utf8");`

from php manual:

> bool mysqli_set_charset ( mysqli $link , string $charset )

And set it before you execute the query.

Answer (score 1):

setting encoding *after* SELECT is a bit late
set it before running any query

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "db");
$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of achieving that is running any of these:

```
// for procedural MySQL (obsolete in PHP 5.4/5.5!)
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';", $link);

// for procedural MySQLi
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8';", $link);

// for MySQLi, function notation
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8");

// for MySQLi, method notation
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

// for PDO
$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$database};charset=utf8", $user, $password);
```

That will guarantee the retrieved data will be returned with UTF-8 encoding.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the charset before your query.

Answer (score 0):

Order is important. You need to set connection encoding before you start executing queries, otherwise it's just too late:

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```

shall be executed just after you connect:

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_DATABASE", "db");
$dbcon = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);    
mysqli_set_charset('utf8');
```